# An easier way to fwrite?

Tags: php, fwrite

fwrite($fh,

```
                mysql_query("UPDATE config SET url='{$url}', shoutcast_url='{$shoutcast_url}', site_name='{$site_name}', site_subtitle='{$site_subtitle}', email_suffix='{$email_suffix}', twitter_username='{$twitter_username}', skype_name='{$skype_name}', phone_number='{$phone_number}'")     
                or die(mysql_error()); ?>);
```

Is there an easier way to fwrite this? (I know that won't work, but obviously it's very time consuming to format it correctly)

Thanks!

Comment: So, you're trying to write '<?php ... ?>' as a string into a file? Just trying to make sure that I understand this correctly.

Comment: Your fwrite appears outside your <?php ?> block, so it will be displayed instead of being executed. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Just want to write a new php file.

Comment: @Sam why do you need that another php file? The way you're doing is awful erraneuos and dangerous one.

Comment: And the code itself is far from being optimal. This `$$field` indeed terrible. You should use a field name, not that variable variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `PHP` tag in `PHP` code...

You must use it in `''` characters like a string.

Comment: You can, if you do this in a string :D
`string = '<?php blabla; ?>` Of course that won't do anything, but saying, that you can't use them seems to be wrong :P

Comment: But then I have to escape it at all...surely there's an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do but if you just want to create some file with some content you may take a look at `file_put_contents()`

Answer (score 0):

As Svisstack said, you should use '':

```
$code = '<?php
$fields = array("url", "shoutcast_url", "site_name", "site_subtitle", "email_suffix", "twitter_username", "skype_name", "phone_number");
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $$field = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]);
}
mysql_query("UPDATE config SET url=\'{$url}\', shoutcast_url=\'{$shoutcast_url}\', site_name=\'{$site_name}\', site_subtitle=\'{$site_subtitle}\', email_suffix=\'{$email_suffix}\', twitter_username=\'{$twitter_username}\', skype_name=\'{$skype_name}\', phone_number=\'{$phone_number}\'") or die(mysql_error());
?>';
fwrite($fh, $code);
```